# InvalidOperationExcption was unhandled

Tags: c#, windows-services

when i type this code :

```
        query = "SELECT DateString FROM table WHERE DateArrivage = 'DefaultValue' ";
        OdbcDataReader DbR = ObAccess.SQLSELECT(query);
        int fCount = DbR.FieldCount;
        if (fCount > 0)
        {

            DateWithoutDate = DbR.GetString(0); // i wan't only first value
            DbR.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            int row_count = DbR.RecordsAffected;
            Console.WriteLine("Query affected " + row_count + " row(s)");
        }
```

it gives the error I wrote in the title,
can somebody help me ?

Comment: I'm sure the exception had more details (a message, to start with) - and you haven't told us *which* line failed, either.

Comment: yes, the line which failed is DateWithoutDate = DbR.GetString(0); it says no data existe for ligne or column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not calling [`Read()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbcdatareader.read.aspx) on your data reader, so logically it's positioned before the first row. I suspect you actually want:

```
query = "SELECT DateString FROM table WHERE DateArrivage = 'DefaultValue' ";
using (OdbcDataReader reader = ObAccess.SQLSELECT(query))
{
    if (reader.Read())
    {
        DateWithoutDate = reader.GetString(0);
    }
    else
    {
        // Whatever you want to do if there are no rows
    }
}
```

It's also worrying that you have names like `ObAccess` and `SQLSELECT`... and you don't appear to be opening and closing the connection in this code, which is normally a good idea. (Don't try to keep a single connection open yourself and reuse it - let the underlying database connection pool do that for you.)

Comment: yes, the problem cames form the DbR.read instruction, I have deleted it because i won't read only one entry,
i tought it is only to know if there is no resutls after a while.
thank you,

Comment: @tp1: What do you mean by "i won't read only one entry"? You're being *very* unclear, but it's definitely pointless to take out `Read()`. You *must* use `Read()`.

Comment: @tp1: No, if you call `Read()` *just once*, it will have the first result from the query. Note that as you haven't specified any kind of ordering, there's no guarantee which result you'll get first. Perhaps that's the real problem? Maybe you just need "ORDER BY ..."? (We don't know what ordering you're interested in...)

Comment: no, i don't really care about database, because i don't know what it contain, but we can easily know if it tooks first or last, because we are selecting dates. it just works, thank you.

Comment: @tp1: No, without any ordering there *is* no logical first or last row in the result set. You could easily read a later date before an earlier date. If you want to make sure you read them in date order, you need to specify that. Still, it seems you're happy now...

Comment: @tp1: Well `ObAccess` isn't very descriptive, and `SQLSELECT` violates the .NET naming conventions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045.aspx